# www and non www resolution issues in my htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have web site that I want to resolve the www and non www issues. I tried to using this below code from the `.htaccess` file. But no result.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.w15.lk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# Remove Trailing Slashes...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: The website serverfault.com is a better place to ask such question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close with your attempt. Try and use this instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.w15.lk/$1 [L,R=302,NC]
```

I've set the `R` flag as 302 to make it a temporary redirect for testing. If this works, change it to 301 to make it permanent.

Don't forget to clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: i have changed and tested. but result is same. please any idea